# How to set up a simple grid based game board in java?

Tags: java, arrays, layout, matrix, grid

I'm currently learning Swing and thought making a game would make the process more interesting for me. I have my JFrame all set up with menu and tool bars, but now I'm constructing a JPanel to serve as the play area, in this case I'd like to make a grid. I can draw one on the panel easily enough using:

```
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    g.setColor(Color.black);
    for(int x = 0 ; x <= getWidth() ; x += 16 ) {
         g.drawLine( x , 0 , x , getHeight() );
     }
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    for(int y = 0 ; y <= getHeight() ; y += 16 ) {
          g.drawLine( 0 , y , getWidth() , y );
```

But this has limited use later on if I want to accurately place and move images on the board. Is there another way I can draw a grid, perhaps using arrays? Just trying to make a clean layout before I dive into interactivity, and would appreciate any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Either create an image using your dimensions or just place the sprites with accordance to the rules that set the grid lines.

```
//Declare some extra variables
int coordX;
int coordY;
final BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("picture.jpg"));
PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();

//Call this every time the mouse is clicked.
Point b = a.getLocation();    
int mouseClickX = (int) b.getX();
int mouseClickY = (int) b.getY();

void place() {//Make a function that establishes ranges to be clicked
    if(mouseClickX < 16 && mouseClickX > 0 && mouseClickY < 16 && mouseClickY > 0)
       coordX = coordY = 0; //places at top corner
    else if()//slot 2, 3, etc...
}



//paintComponent method:
g.drawImage(image, coordX, coordY, this); //set coordinates in 0,0
```

in addition to your current option
If you want your game elements to be Swing components, then [GridBagLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/GridBagLayout.html) is what you are looking for. While it takes a bit of getting used to, it is the most customize able layout provided by Swing.

More information on using GridBagLayout can be found [in this tutorial by oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could create a grid of JPanels all held in a GridLayout. If you wanted each cell to hold a draggable picture, then put the images in an ImageIcon, the icon in a JLabel and add the JLabel to one of the cells of the JPanel grid. If the cells use GridBagLayout, then a single JLabel will be displayed by default in the JPanel cell's center. To drag and drop, give the JLabels MouseListeners and MouseMotionListeners. If clicked on, removed the JLabel from the JPanel and move it to the top level window's glass pane. etc...